# Is network connection needed for build and run phonegap app?

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, phonegap-build

I have building the app by using phonegap.

First, I have connected my laptop with internet connection, Everything is working.

On same project, i have tried without internet connection, It is showing

```
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\Smargav\Projects\Done\pla
yer\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\Smargav\Projects\Done\playe
r

add to body class: platform-android

Running command: cmd "/s /c "D:\Smargav\Projects\Done\player\platforms\android\c
ordova\build.bat""

ANDROID_HOME=D:\Smargav\DownladImg\android-sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60

Running: D:\Smargav\Projects\Done\player\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug
 -b D:\Smargav\Projects\Done\player\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.
daemon=true



FAILURE:
Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

>
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.


> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+.

     Required by:

         :android:unspecified


>
Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.


>
Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/t
ools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
```

I am getting the above error.

What is the mistake in this?

I have checked in google, I got as No need internet connection for phonegap build.

Then How can i solve this one?

Comment: This is a gradle error. You do need an internet connection to download new android dependencies. They will be cached after the first download.

Comment: Then. How can i work on offline? any option?

Comment: Not sure, never made a phonegap application. You'll need to at least download the PhoneGap files and Android SDK maybe? So I don't think you can completely work offline for a new app without initially downloading the source files.

Comment: @Deen, There is a `--save` option you can use with Cordova. Here is a [recent blog post](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/12/14/plugins-release.html) so you can see the difference.